# Creating a web server / servlet container in Java - Standing on the shoulders of giants

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, webserver, akka

First and foremost: I want to state that this is mostly a personal exercise.  There are plenty of containers and servers out there (Tomcat, Jetty, Winstone) that satisfy the needs of the market.

The other day I came across the [Akka](http://akka.io/) project and, having had a lot of fun with Erlang in the past, decided that it would be really cool to use it to build a functional web server.

Then I started daydreaming.  What if I could use modern frameworks and build, in a code golf way, a web server that almost completely "stood on the shoulders of giants"?  That is to say: *how much of other people's work could I manage to use.*

Ideally the requirements would resemble something like:

- Fault tolerant, clusterable, distributed
- Easy to configure
- Supports HTTP, HTTPS, and AJP on configurable ports
- Supports interface binding and multiple domains
- Supports JSP, Jython, etc. through a pluggable interface
- Supports modules that allow implementation of things like WebDAV, proxy, and URL rewrite

My biggest stumbling block at this juncture is **how on earth do you use Jasper, Jetty, GlassFish or anything** to interpret JSPs without worrying about all the other stuff, like networking, that they bring?

Any other suggestions for features would be highly awesome.  I'm also investigating non-traditional configuration methods to see if there's anything out there that I like more than XML or properties files.  For those of you who are familiar with Apache, sometimes you need a little scripting and sometimes you just need key/value pairs.

So, in any case, hit me up with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least Tomcat has implemented its JSP engine as a module. It's not released separately and it *might* require some work to fully dis-couple it from the rest of the Tomcat code.

It's got a separate name (Jasper) and [its own Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html). It's found in the `org.apache.jasper` package (and below).

Comment: I've seen this a few times and I guess I just feel like there *has* to be a better way.  We're talking about calling an ant task from inside of my web server to create compiled JSPs.  I guess I'll keep this method in mind though.

Comment: The ant task is just *one frontend*. You can look at the whole `org.apache.jasper` package, look for its entry point and use that programmatically. The fact that there is an ant task only proves that the code is **not** dependent on a running Tomcat instance.

Comment: I'll look into it.  If nobody comes up with a better sort of bolt-in component then I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer after I stew on it a bit.  I'm still not sure I like the JspC route but if it's all I can get without implementing my own container from scratch then it's what I'll take.  Thanks.

Comment: I have Jasper separated from Tomcat up to version 9. Check instructions there https://tjws.sourceforge.net/jasper.html